# Task.WaitAll vs serialized task.results?

Tags: c#, task

Ignoring async/await solutions is there any difference between these 2 sets of code? would you really need Task.WaitAll in this case? Would there be any negative consequences to omitting it?

```
public void ExampleA()
{
    Task<object> fooTask = _someFactory.StartFooTask();
    Task<object> barTask = _someFactory.StartBarTask();

    //misc code ...

    _fooResult = fooTask.Result;
    _barResult = barTask.Result;

    //more misc code ...
}

public void ExampleB()
{
    Task<object> fooTask = _someFactory.StartFooTask();
    Task<object> barTask = _someFactory.StartBarTask();

    //misc code ...

    Task.WaitAll(fooTask, barTask);

    _fooResult = fooTask.Result;
    _barResult = barTask.Result;

    //more misc code ...
}
```

exampleA makes even more sense to me, especially in the case, where there might be some more computes that could happen as one tasks results might be needed sooner then the others? if by chance the one needed, actually finishes earlier.

```
public void ExampleC()
{
    Task<object> fooTask = _someFactory.StartFooTask();
    Task<object> barTask = _someFactory.StartBarTask();

    //misc code ...

    _fooResult = fooTask.Result;

    // more misc code requiring _fooResult ...

    _barResult = barTask.Result;

    // more misc code requiring _barResult...
}
```

Comment: One issue i see with `WaitAll` is, if there is an exception in any of the tasks it will throw `AggregateException`. Whereas in `ExampleA` you would know which task threw the exception and can have mechanism to handle them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that both (all) methods completed you'd use `WaitAll`, otherwise exceptions in first task will prevent call to `.Result` or the second task and hence second method may not be completed by the time method exits.

Overall behavior will be very close

- there is small difference when exceptions are thrown (`.WhenAll` vs. individual `.Result`),
- as you've poined out you can fit some code between `.Result` calls if you don't have `WaitAll`,
- both versions will deadlock in ASP.Net/Winforms/WPF contexts.

Comment: I'm working with a console application. So not worried about deadlocks caused the mentioned contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, both methods will block until `fooTask` and `barTask` have completed.

There are differences occurring of course. You are initialising and tearing down synchronisation primitives different but nothing that you will notice.

In the 3rd snippet, the behaviour you describe will occur. However, you should use continuations (`Task.ContinueWith` etc) if you want results to be processed concurrently.

I can't address this code without passing on the classic advice - if you can avoid it, never call `Task.Wait` or use `Task<T>.Result` to block. Your colleagues will hate you.